# OpenLDAP on Windows and gssapi32

Tags: kerberos, openldap

Upon trying to run OpenLDAP on Windows after a non-eventful installation, I get the error that gssapi32.dll is missing.  Reinstalling does nothing to alleviate the problem, nor does altering the install settings/backend.

Comment: +1 from developer. Great question! Keep going!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gssapi32.dll` is part of MIT [Kerberos for Windows](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/dist/).

---

You may need to add `%ProgramFiles%\MIT\KfW\bin` to the `%PATH%` variable, for OpenLDAP to find the libraries.

Comment: Mine on windows10: %ProgramFiles%\MIT\Kerberos\bin